# State Machine Pattern in Haskell : infinite type error

Tags: haskell

I was trying to implement a state machine in Haskell. A simplified version is the following:

In any state, you can feed the machine an integer and you get back an integer. In state A, the machine doubles its inputs. In state B, the machine just gives you back your input. Whenever you see a zero in either state, change to the other state. Otherwise, the state does not change.

Here's the my approach: just have each state be a function which returns both its output and the function corresponding to the other state.

```
module Main where

a x | x == 0 = (0,b)
a x = (2*x, a)

b x | x == 0 = (0,a)
b x = (x, b)

evalstate s [] = []
evalstate s (x:xs) = (v:evalstate s' xs)
    where (v,s') = s x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ evalstate a [1,1,2,3,4,0,2,3,3]
```

Unfortunately, the types for `a` and `b` are infinite and GHC complains:

`Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t = t1 -> (t2, t)`

What is the way to express this pattern in Haskell?

I could of course do something like:

```
s 'a' x | x == 0 = (0,'b')
```

using character codes for the state, but the function pattern seems more elegant.

Comment: Task for the reader: Make this pattern more common and create a monadic interface for it.

Comment: On a point of style: it is usually clearer if you say `a 0 = (0,b)` instead of `a x | x == 0 = (0,b)`.

Comment: Instead of a character code, I suggest using a data type, like `data State = A | B`. but the first one is nice too.

Comment: Food for thought: try writing the type signature for `a`. It's something like `Int -> (Int, f)`, but that's too vague. What's `f`? It's the same as the type for `a`. So the whole thing is now `Int -> (Int, (Int -> (Int, Int f)))` Wait a minute...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are trying to define a state machine with the type

```
type SM = Int -> (Int, SM)
```

but Haskell doesn't allow this. You have to use `data` or `newtype` to introduce a new named type:

```
newtype SM = SM (Int -> (Int, SM))
```

Below is your program with this minor change applied, so that it now compiles and behaves as expected:

```
module Main where

newtype SM = SM (Int -> (Int, SM))

a = SM a'
    where
    a' x | x == 0 = (0, b)
    a' x = (2 * x, a)

b = SM b'
    where
    b' x | x == 0 = (0, a)
    b' x = (x, b)

evalstate s [] = []
evalstate (SM s) (x : xs) = (v:evalstate s' xs)
    where (v, s') = s x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ evalstate a [1,1,2,3,4,0,2,3,3]
```

Comment: Specifically, the reason Haskell doesn't allow `type SM` is because it is recursive.  Type inference for equi-recursive types is undecidable (I think), so you have to introduce a constructor at the value level to help the typechecker see what's going on.

Comment: Equirecursive type inference is more complex but decidable, but allowing equirecursive types to be inferred turns many common programming errors into typeable programs. This is annoying because it tends to delays the point at which programmer errors are caught from where functions are defined to where they are used.